# Interchanging Lebesgue Integral and Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, solution-verification, proof-writing

**STATEMENT**

> "Let $(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ be an arbitrary measure space, let $U$ be an open interval of $\Bbb R$ with the Euclidean Topology and let $f:X \times U \to \Bbb C$. If:

> - $\text{a.e. } x \in X, (y \in U \to f(x,y)) \text{ is continuosly differentiable}$
> - $\exists g \in L^1(\mu): \text{a.e. } x \in X, \forall y \in U, |\partial_{y}f(x,y)| \leq g(x)$
> - $\forall y \in U, (x \in X\to f(x,y)) \in L^1(\mu)$

> then:
> $$
> \forall y \in U, \hspace{2mm} \partial_{y} \left( \int_Xf(x,y)d\mu \right) = \int_X\partial_{y}f(x,y)d\mu
> $$

**ATTEMPT AT A PROOF**

Begin by fixing $y_0 \in U$ and by evaluating the following quotient for $h>0$ such that $(y_0+h) \in U$:
$$
\frac{1}{h} \left( \int_X f(x,y_0+h) d\mu - \int_X f(x,y_0) d\mu \right) = \int_X \frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)}{h} d\mu \hspace{1cm} (1)
$$
Now, applying the Mean Value Theorem we obtain:
$$
\text{a.e. } x \in X, \forall h, \exists \xi_{x,h} \text{ between }y_0\text{ and }(y_0+h) : 
\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)}{h} = \partial_{y}f(x,\xi_{x,h}) \hspace{1cm} (2)
$$
Let then $\{h_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ be a sequence of positive numbers converging to $0$ such that $\forall n \in \Bbb N, (y_0+h_n) \in U$; hence define:
$$
\text{a.e. } x \in X, g_n(x) := \partial_{y}f(x,\xi_{x,h_n}) \hspace{1cm} (3)
$$
and notice that this yields a sequence of measurable (see (2)) functions on $X$ which is a.e. dominated by the Lebesgue integrable function $g$ on $X$ and which converges a.e. pointwise to $\partial_{y} f(x,y_0)$ by the continuity of $(y \in Y \to \partial_{y}f(x,y))$. Therefore, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem:
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_X \frac{f(x,y_0+h_n)-f(x,y_0)}{h_n} d\mu = \int_X \partial_{y} f(x,y_0) d\mu \hspace{1cm} (4)
$$
The conclusion thus follows from the sequential characterization of the limit as $h \to 0$.

**QUESTION**

I would like to know wether this proof is correct or it needs some corrections. Also, the statement is loosely inspired by Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement), where unfortunately the associated proof is not coherent with the statement itself.

---

Any comment or answer is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself more clearly.

---

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Anne Bauval in the comments, I could have directly dominated the quotients $\text{a.e. } x \in X$ by applying the Mean Value Theorem, in which case the continuity of the partial derivatives becomes superfluous.

Comment: It is correct but lengthy. Instead of introducing $\xi_{x,h},$ simply notice that $\left|\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)}h\right|\le g(x),$ and (by definition) $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)}h=\partial_{y} f(x,y_0).$

Comment: @AnneBauval You mean that I could have applied the Mean Value Theorem and directly conclude that the quotients were dominated $\{a.e. \} x \in X$? Also, in that case I wouldn't need the continuity of the partial derivative, is that correct? Thank you anyway for your comment!

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks again! (By "anyway" I meant to say "regardless of you answering these new questions"; I am sorry if it seemed to have a negative connotation I am actually very grateful for your time).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! I am too touchy...